# "gatsby-node.js" created a page and didn't pass the path to the component

Tags: gatsby, prismic.io

I'm trying to use prismic and gatsby to dynamically generate some pages [following this tutorial](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/sourcing-from-prismic/).  I created the UID in prismic, and it looks like it's sending the path, but I get the following error:

> ERROR #11322
>
> Your site's "gatsby-node.js" created a page and didn't pass the path to the component.
>
> The page object passed to createPage:

```
{
    "path": "/heatx",
    "context": {
        "id": "Prismic__Article__XkTInhAAACIAtG2G"
    }
}
```

As you can see... it has a path.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Ah, the problem was that I wasn't giving the component the template correctly:

```
 const pageTemplates = {
    Article: path.resolve('./src/templates/article.jsx'),
  }

  pages.data.allPrismicArticle.edges.forEach(edge => {
    createPage({
      path: `/${edge.node.uid}`,
      component: pageTemplates.Article,
      context: {
        id: edge.node.id,
      },
    })
  })
}
```

Comment: i was having the same issue and and added  path.resolve and works , thanks for this post

Answer (score 1):

It may also be the reason for typing 'component' as 'components'. As it was in my case. Hope you do not make a typing mistake.